# What are all possible linux path chars that need escaping

Tags: java, regex, linux, scala

I'm wondering what are all the char needed escaping for a linux path. For example, path /home/user1/My Music/song 1.mp3 would need to be escaped in a shell for ls command 'ls /home/user1/My\ Music/song\ 1.mp3'.

I want to write a function that takes in a String as a path and escape all needed chars.  In scala I have:

```
  def normalizePath(path: String): String = {
var normPath = path.replaceAll(" ", "\\\\ ")
normPath = normPath.replaceAll("\\]", "\\\\]")
normPath = normPath.replaceAll("\\[", "\\\\[")

normPath
```

}

Knowing that there is more char that need escaping.  Also, this might be able to be done by one command(more complex regex)?

Comment: yes `string normalize(string s) { return "\"" + s + "\""; }`

Comment: Why not just not use a shell for this in the first place?

Comment: The answer depends on where you plan on using the path. For example, if it's going to be passed to the shell, then you need to escape the special characters that shell interprets (which might include '!', '*', '?', etc., and perhaps depends on what shell is being used). If you're putting the path into a URL, you'll need to escape a different set of characters, and use a different mechanism for escaping (%-encode). And if you're using the path directly with a Linux system call, you don't need to escape things at all.

Comment: When you have to deal with so many backslashes you can use the multi-line string literal in which backslashes do not needed to be escaped. E.g. `"\\\\"` would become `"""\\"""`.

Comment: Invalid characters (as well as other path restrictions) depend partially upon the file-system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not relay on this. There are plenty of way to defeat this (e.g. setting the `FS` environment variable). Just use the `ProcessBuilder` class to pass command line argument.

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "/home/user1/My Music/song 1.mp3");
proc.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to quote strings than escape them, I think. The algorithm for single quote is:

- append a single-quote char to open
- for each char in the original string,

  - if it is a single quote, append single quote, backslash, single quote, single quote (i.e. close the quote, append escaped single quote, reopen quote)
  - otherwise append the char itself
- append a single-quote char to close

So that is pretty easy.

However, I like the ProcessBuilder answer, that is even easier if it works for you.

Avoiding the shell entirely is both a performance and a security win too, if you don't need any shell features and just want to spawn a process.

If you do want to use escaping, I'd suggest whitelisting instead of blacklisting characters. i.e. escape anything that isn't [a-zA-Z0-9_] or something. Any character can be escaped except newline. backslash followed by newline means "remove both the backslash and the newline" - if outside of quotes. Inside double quotes, I think you can escape newline with backslash then newline. Inside single quotes, I don't think you have to (or can) escape newline, just append the newline character.

A good reference is the UNIX98 spec for "Shell Command Language" http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes prevent shell expansion, so all you need is:

```
def normalizePath(path: String): String = "'" + path.replace("'", "\\'") + "'"
```